# How to extract last modified date of a link using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
```

Here is the data I extracted with Beautiful Soup:

```html
<pre>Name   Last modified      Size</pre>
<hr/>
<pre>
   <a href="../">../</a>
   <a href="0.1.0/">0.1.0/</a>
   21-Oct-2020 14:06    -
</pre>
```

I am trying to get the 'Last Modified' data associated with the 'a' tag.  In this example, I want to make a `dict` with the key being '0.1.0' (I know how to extract this) and the value being '21-Oct-2020 14:06'.

**EDIT**

OK, so after playing around I was able to get the text:

```py
(Pdb) soup.findAll("pre")[1].get_text()
'../\n0.1.0/  21-Oct-2020 14:06    -\n'
```

I guess just iterating around each 'pre' tag will do it

thx

Comment: So you want to get the text in the `<pre>` node and retrieve the timestamp? Is there any other text after the "-"?

Comment: The fact the text is the last modified date is irrelevant. The title of your question makes it look significant. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Do you want your result to be `21-Oct-2020`?

Comment: @PeterWood, you could be a little less abrasive to be honest. I realize the question might've been better but your phrasing is leaving a little to be desired

Comment: Thx everyone for the edit suggestions, they have been applied.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for that !!

```
import re
data = re.findall(r'\d{2}\-\w{3}\-\d{4} \d{2}\:\d{2}',requests.get(url))[0]
```